# Typescript modules and importing - references?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

**Models/Objects/A.ts**

```
module App.Models.Objects
{
    export class A
    {}
}
```

**Models/Abstracts/ISomethingElse.ts**

```
module App.Models.Abstracts
{
    export interface ISomethingElse
    {
        A: A;
    }
}
```

How do i use the module `App.Models.Objects` from the `ISomethingElse.ts` file?

I have tried referencing:

```
/// <reference path="../Objects/A.ts" />
```

But it still cannot find `A` because it's in the module. How do i import it?

I have tried importing:

```
/// <reference path="../Objects/A.ts" />
import A = require("App.Models.Objects");
```

But it still doesn't compile.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: As module names are different, in ISomethingElse you should refer A by its complete name: "App.Models.Objects.A"   I think this is the only problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're not using an editor that takes care of the references for you, the relative reference path you've used is wrong. The following should work:

```js
/// <reference path="../objects/A.ts"/>
    
module App.Models.Abstracts
{
  export interface ISomethingElse
  {
    a: App.Models.Objects.A;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm more interested in the import part so that i can alias that big module name. Can you not import the module rather than reference as you've put? like a using in c#, or an import in java, or a use in php?

Comment: You're using internal modules here (which I believe are now at long last correctly called namespaces), you can't require a namespace as it not a real JS module (in the CommonJS, AMD, ES6 etc. sense). If you want to use require or ES6 import with your module you need to have a top level export in your .ts file.

Comment: You can use a type alias if all you want to do is shorten the type name. e.g. type A = App.Models.Objects.A